# If I input password incorrect for one time then it will never pass until open a totally new termal

Tags: command-line, password

When I input correct password for sudo, it works well. But once when I input a wrong password by mistake, it will always gives **Sorry, try again.** and **sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts**. Only when I open a new terminal it will pass again.
And if I leave a terminal in password inputting status, I will never pass even in a new terminal nor in tty terminal.
Can anyone explain or solve this? Thanks!

Comment: If it's jumping straight to `3 incorrect password attempts` that's likely a problem with `PAM` (either one of the configuration files in `/etc/pam.d` or one of the PAM modules itself) I think

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, avoid putting in the wrong password.

As an explanaition: you notice that such system behaviour makes it more difficult for malicious users to break into your system. Attempts to break in may involve trying thousands and thousands of passwords. The time needed to break your system strongly depends on the strength of your password. If, in addition, the system itself does not allow to quickly enter and reenter different passwordt, the time will be increased many more: rather than 0.1 second, it then takes many seconds to attempt each different pasword.

Comment: Thanks! I understand this. I'm tring hard to input right everytime.